# Displaying a different popup messaqe based on what is clicked

Tags: jquery, popup

I need assistance with creating a jquery function that will display a popup message when an image is clicked. Each image will have a different popup message. Here's my HTML code:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="/face.jpg" />
            <span>
                <div class="bubble">
                    THIS IS MY POPUP MESSAGE 1
                </div>
            </span>
        </a>    
    </td>   

    <td>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="/face.jpg" />
            <span>
                <div class="bubble">
                    THIS IS MY POPUP MESSAGE 2
                </div>
            </span>
        </a>    
    </td>

    <td>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="/face.jpg" />
            <span>
                <div class="bubble">
                    THIS IS MY POPUP MESSAGE 3
                </div>
            </span>
        </a>    
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: window.open ("http://www.javascript-coder.com","mywindow");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you the same level answer as that of the question. My tweak is, however, you must include jQuery UI

**CSS**

```
a span {display: none}
```

Download and include jQuery UI

**HTML**

```
<script src="javascripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**JS**

```
$('a').click(function() {
  $(this).find('span').dialog();
})
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I was able to resolve it based on your answer. Here's what I have:                                                                     $('a.hover1').mouseover(function() { $(this).find('span').show();
 }).mouseout(function(){
  $(this).find('span').hide();
 });